# XML Validation - Namespace Trouble

Tags: xml, namespaces, schema

I am new to XML. This is a homework assignment. I have given it my best but I cannot get the instance document to validate. I keep getting the error of

> "Cannot find the declaration of element 'sites'."

I think I may have declared some of the namespaces incorrectly or maybe the schemaLocations. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The homework steps:

- > In the sites.xml file, add a namespace declaration to the root sites
  >   element, associating the xs prefix with the URI for the XML Schema
  >   namespace. Specify the default namespace ht tp://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites for the file. Specify
  >   sites.xsd as the location of the schema for the default namespace.
- > In the sites.xsd file, in the root element, specify the target namespace
  >   as ht tp://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites, and then associate the
  >   prefix cc with the target namespace. Associate the prefix sm with the
  >   namespace ht tp://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9. Specify that
  >   elements are qualified by default, and that attributes are unqualified
  >   by default.
- > Add code to import the schema for the
  >   ht tp://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 namespace from the
  >   location ht tp://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd.
- > Immediately following the declaration of the totalPages element, add a
  >   reference to the urlset element from the
  >   ht tp://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 namespace.

The instance document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
    <!--
       Filename:         sites.xml
       Supporting Files: sites.xsd
    -->
    <sites xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="sites.xsd">
        <site>
            <name>Weekend Fun Snacks</name>
            <totalPages>127</totalPages>
            <urlset xmlns:sm="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" sm:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"> 
             <url>
                <loc>http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/?cat=58</loc>
             </url>
             <url>
                <loc>http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/?cat=2</loc>
                <lastmod>2017-12-29T06:03:34+00:00</lastmod>
             </url>
             <url>
                <loc>http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/?cat=15</loc>
                <lastmod>2017-12-29T05:24:04+00:00</lastmod>
             </url>
             <url>
                <loc>http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/?cat=93</loc>
             </url>
             <url>
                <loc>http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/?cat=55</loc>
             </url>
           </urlset> 
        </site>
        <site>
            <name>Paleo Snacks</name>
            <totalPages>52</totalPages>
            <urlset xmlns:sm="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" sm:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"> 
             <url>
                <loc>http://example.com/primalsnacks/?cat=6</loc>
             </url>
             <url>
                <loc>http://example.com/primalsnacks/?cat=18</loc>
                <lastmod>2017-09-19T17:13:19+00:00</lastmod>
             </url>
             <url>
                <loc>http://example.com/primalsnacks/?cat=54</loc>
                <lastmod>2017-09-19T15:24:01+00:00</lastmod>
             </url>
             <url>
                <loc>http://example.com/primalsnacks/?cat=52</loc>
                <lastmod>2017-09-28T21:03:11+00:00</lastmod>
             </url>
             <url>
                <loc>http://example.com/primalsnacks/?cat=201</loc>
                <lastmod>2017-10-06T07:03:26+00:00</lastmod>
             </url>
             <url>
                <loc>http://example.com/primalsnacks/?cat=11</loc>
             </url>
           </urlset> 
        </site>
        <site>
            <name>Veg Snacks</name>
            <totalPages>17</totalPages>
            <urlset xmlns:sm="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" sm:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"> 
             <url>
                <loc>http://example.com/vegsnacks/?cat=102</loc>
             </url>
             <url>
                <loc>http://example.com/vegsnacks/?cat=23</loc>
             </url>
             <url>
                <loc>http://example.com/vegsnacks/?cat=1</loc>
             </url>
             <url>
                <loc>http://example.com/vegsnacks/?cat=55</loc>
                <lastmod>2017-06-12T08:05:32+00:00</lastmod>
             </url>
             <url>
                <loc>http://example.com/vegsnacks/?cat=201</loc>
             </url>
             <url>
                <loc>http://example.com/vegsnacks/?cat=87</loc>
             </url>
           </urlset> 
        </site>
    </sites>
```

The .xsd document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="cc:http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites" xmlns:sm="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xs:element name="sites">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="site" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
               <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                     <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                     <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="totalPages"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

The namespaces don't match. The schema is for namespace `cc:http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites`, but the instance document is in namespace `http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites`